# How should I install a chimney for a wood stove in my garage?

Tags: garage, chimney, woodstove

I have a new construction 24' x 48' garage that is two stories.  It is partial block construction (to middle of 2nd floor) and finished on the top with wood (trusses etc). The floor plan is very open.  I plan on installing a wood stove listed below:

**SKU Number:** 1015370

**Manufacturers Number:** B2350B
**Brand:** United States Stove
**Fuel Type:** Wood/Coal
**Hopper Capacity:** 50 lb.
**Log Size:** 23 in.
**BTUs:** 106,000

I want to install it on the first floor (concrete floor).  My question is where should I run my chimney?

Should I plan on going up through the ceiling of the first floor, into the second floor and through that ceiling into the attic, then through the roof? (the garage is something like 22+ feet tall to the eaves) I could build a steel grate to be around the pipe to prevent anyone from touching it etc on the second floor.  I would obviously use double wall pipe for the length between the floors, and preferable single wall in the first and second floor in the "open air" spaces to get the most form the heat, followed by double wall for attic/roof. I have heard of people going through closets, etc, does that seem ok?

My other option is to go through the block wall on the first floor, but then have an ugly, and expensive run of about 20ft insulated chimney pipe to get the desired height above the roof to ensure proper draft.

I am doing this on as tight of a budget as possible. I have considered pellet stoves, but have a steady unlimited local supply of wood available.  I realize it may not heat the second floor completely, so I will supplement with another type of heater up there when needed.  I do not have hvac installed in the garage, and would rather not install any. The garage is a very basic rectangle shape. I plan on insulating it very well.

Comment: Just a heads up that there may be code issues installing wood stoves in garages in your region.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming open flame heaters are allowed in a garage in your area, carefully check all clearance requirements for the stove and flue.  I would encourage you to adapt to triple wall insulated flue pipe at the ceiling of the first floor and stay with insulated pipe the rest of the way. Do not attempt to change back to single wall pipe.

You may want to install a couple of floor registers to help take some of the warm air from the first floor to the second floor. Remember, heat rises, and depending on how long you run the stove, the heat will eventually fill the second floor.  Some simple electric fans can also be placed strategically to move the warm air around and even out the temp in the building.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure maximum heat usage I would run it up through the second floor and out the roof there using a single skin flue ( if this is allowable by code and manufactures specs) and a decorative (perforated/decro) flue cover [image: Perforated flue]

You can then get ceiling rings to cover the necessary gap around the flue to combustible floor surfaces which will match the decro you choose.

One advantage of running it out the wall is for cleaning of the flue if you use wood that tends to soot the flue up as you can put an access tee out side the house.  But you do waste a lot of heat this way.